# Height em video html5

Tags: html5, vídeo

Estou usando a tag ***video*** do *html5*.
Queria fazer com que meu video ficasse com o *height* 100%, no entanto, assim que eu uso o atributo *height*, ele reposiciona ao meu video e nao aumenta ele.
Queria fazer um menu logo abaixo do video como nesse [site](http://www.popupdesign.com.br/)

Dessa mesma forma porém com efeitos diferentes.
O que estou a fazer de errado?

```
 <div id="video" >
       <video src="video/League-warrios.mp4" width="100%" height="100%" loop/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para o elemento `<video/>` ficar com uma altura de 100%, o elemento pai, neste caso `<div id="video"/>` tem que ter uma altura definida.

De igual forma, a altura deve ser facultada através da propriedade de CSS `height`.

Duas soluções podem ser implementadas, tudo depende do objetivo final:

## Solução 100% x 100%

Nesta solução, o vídeo fica com a largura e altura total do seu contentor, sem respeitar o *aspect ratio* do mesmo.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
}
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
#rodape {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" loop autoplay>
    <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
<div id="rodape">Meu Rodapé</div>
```

## Solução preservando o *aspect ratio*

Nesta solução, o vídeo não "estica" nem "encolhe", mantém o seu *aspect ratio* intacto.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
video {
  height: 99%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
#rodape {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" loop autoplay>
    <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
<div id="rodape">Meu Rodapé</div>
```

Comment: @user23633 Feito, tens agora uma solução para 100% x 100% sem respeitar o _aspect ratio_ do vídeo. Analisa a primeira parte da resposta.

Comment: hmm interessante ele realmente nao modificou o video agora so fala mesmo o posicionamento porque logo depois que acabar tudo irei ultilizar uns media queries para deixar responsivo mais de priore agora eu quero fixar ele no topo e que ele fique ajustado ao tamanho da tela como naquele link que eu mencionei o meu menu ja esta pronto voce comentou que essa era a primeira parte tem mais se sim aguardo ancioso :)

Comment: A "primeira parte" porque a resposta tem duas partes, sendo a primeira o que procuravas, 100%x100% independentemente do _aspect ratio_ do vídeo. Tecnicamente, o problema da tua pergunta está resolvido. Se precisares de ajuda com outros detalhes, deverás colocar nova(s) pergunta(s) focando-te nesses detalhes apenas.